# Trying to understand では、能力者だけ集めようとしてうまく回るかというと、うまくいかないと思われる

Tags: meaning, sentence

> 「能力のある人間しか要らない」考。
> 株主資本主義者やそれに影響されている人は、よくこのことを口にする。では、能力者だけ**集めようとしてうまく回るかというと、うまくいかないと思われる**。そんな職場は安心ができないからだ

The beginning of this paragraph is pretty understandable, but the highlighted part after that really trips me up. Usually even if I don't understand some parts I would still have a vague feeling for how it should be, but this one just completely defeats me. I would be very grateful if someone could break it down grammatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think you know [というと](https://hedgehog-japanese.com/grammar/jlpt-n2/toieba/) "if we talk about"

> 【意味】
> ～と聞いてイメージするのは
> ～と聞いて思い付くのは

2. 思われる: 思う + [自発のられる](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) "it is thought that"

> （自発） 動作がはっきりと意図しないで、自然に起きていることを表す。

3. [回る](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B):

> 物事が進む。はかどる。
> 仕事がうまく回る

Therefore, a rough rendering would be:

> では、能力者だけ集めようとしてうまく回るかというと、うまくいかないと思われる。
> So, if we try to gather only capable people, can we successfully pull it off? It seems like it won't go smoothly.